# mysql queries whose results are not quite right

Tags: mysql, laravel, where-clause, codeigniter-4, sql-in

I have a database :
[image: example database]

I want to retrieve data with conditions where the card number is 7689, with product ID 73 or 71.

```
 $this->cekModel->where('card_number', 7689)->where('id_product ', '73')orWhere('id_product', '71')->FindAll();
```

The result must display 2 data, i.e. which has id = 1 and id = 4 but I only get one data using the query above

Comment: Must? You’re wrong. Are you aware how the “or” condition works?

Comment: actually I use the code $ this-> checkModel-> where ('card_number', 7689) -> where ('id_product', '73') but it only returns one record

Comment: Results from mysql queries are always right, unless you have found a bug in mysql, which you did not.

Comment: other things aside, isn't it supposed to be `or_where`?

Comment: [or_where() was formerly known as orwhere(), which has been removed.](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: `$this-> checkModel-> where ('card_number', 7689) -> where ('id_product', '73')` is supposed to return only one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `whereIn()` do what you want?

```
$this->cekModel
    ->where('card_number', 7689)
    ->whereIn('id_product', array(71, 73))
    ->FindAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->cekModel
->where('card_number', 7689)
->whereIn('id_product', array(71, 73))
->FindAll();
```

The code above does not work correctly on my console (returns wrong results).
I tried modification and it worked.

```
 $data=['71','73'];
 $this->cekModel
    ->where('card_number', 7689)
    ->whereIn('id_product', $data)
    ->FindAll();
```

Thank you..